# Powershell Array in get-adcomputer

Tags: powershell

I have a script I am creating where I want to use an array in a Get-ADComputer -searchbase, either is does not work or I just can not find the syntax.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

```
$GroupOU = @("A","B","C")

while ($Num -lt $OULength)
    {
        $OU = $GroupOU[$Num]

    $HostName = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Workstations,OU=$OU,dc=ad,dc=COMPANY,dc=com" -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Select -Exp Name | Sort-Object

$Num = $Num++
```

Comment: You can use a `foreach` loop instead. `Foreach ($OU in $GroupOU) { Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Workstations,OU=$OU,dc=ad,dc=COMPANY,dc=com" -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Select -Exp Name | Sort-Object}`. Sorry for the poor example, I'm on my phone. They blocked SO at work :(. You also was `Sort-Object` before `Select-Object`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was thinking of trying a "foreach" but I am getting the same type errors - Get-ADComputer : Directory object not found

Comment: That means it didn't find anything

Comment: Yes, that actually did work. It was my own fault the -searchbase for the first OU was another layer down, which was causing the issue. A quick edit and it's all working now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome man. Keep up the good work!